# Get row & column values in web table using python web driver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How to get particular row & column values in web table using python web driver. I have been trying but i can't get it. please any one give me idea for how we get row & column values. Here my codes

```
start="//*[@id='p1']/div/table/tbody/tr["
end= str(i)+ "]/td[1]/a"
row1=driver.find_element_by_xpath(start + end)
print row1.text
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,its working fine on my system:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/programming-python-4th-e-d/p/itmczzj4gpfrr6bs?pid=9789350232873&icmpid=reco_pp_hSame_book_1")
data=[]
for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="mprod-similar-prod-table"]//tr'):
  tds=tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
  if tds: 
    data= [td.text for td in tds]
print "3730" in data[2] #or whatever is the current price
```