# Marking off checkboxes in a table that match a specific text

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox, html-table, row

I have a table (screenshot below) where I want to mark off the checkboxes that have the text "Xatu Auto Test" in the same row using selenium python.

[image]

I've tried following these two posts:

- [Iterating Through a Table in Selenium Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234879/iterating-through-a-table-in-selenium-very-slow)
- [Get row & column values in web table using python web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907134/get-row-column-values-in-web-table-using-python-web-driver)

But I couldn't get those solutions to work on my code.

My code:

```
form = self.browser.find_element_by_id("quotes-form")

try:
    rows = form.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
        for row in rows:
            columns = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
            for column in columns:
                if column.text == self.group_name:
                    column.find_element_by_name("quote_id").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

The checkboxes are never clicked and I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

This is the HTML when I inspect with FirePath:

```
<form id="quotes-form" action="/admin/quote/delete_multiple" method="post" name="quotesForm">
    <table class="table table-striped table-shadow">
        <thead>
        <tbody id="quote-rows">
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="document-column">
            <td>47</td>
            <td class="nobr">
            <td class="nobr">
            <td class="nobr">
            <td class="nobr">
                <a title="Xatu Auto Test Data: No" href="http://192.168.56.10:5001/admin/quote/47/">Xatu Auto Test</a>
            </td>
            <td>$100,000</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">1,000</td>
            <td class="nobr">Processing...</td>
            <td class="nobr">192.168....</td>
            <td/>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="47" name="quote_id"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="quote-rows-footer">
</table>
<div class="btn-toolbar" style="text-align:center; width:100%;">
```

Comment: Very hard to follow without seeing the full code. are you sure `if column.text == self.group_name:` comparison is correct?

Comment: That is the full code of what I'm trying to do in this situation. Oh and sorry that I didn't explain about "self.group_name". You can replace that with "Xatu Auto Test".

Comment: Yes I believe the comparison is correct. I don't get any syntax errors if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a quick look, I reckon this line needs changing as you're trying to access `column`'s `quote_id`, it should be `row`'s:

From:

```
column.find_element_by_name("quote_id").click()
```

To:

```
row.find_element_by_name("quote_id").click()
```

P.S. Provided that like @Saifur commented, you have your comparison done correctly.

#### Updated:

I have run a simulation and indeed the checkbox is ticked if changing `column` to `row`, simplified version:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('your-form-sample.html')
form = driver.find_element_by_id("quotes-form")

rows = form.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    for column in columns:
        # I changed this to the actual string provided your comparison is correct
        if column.text == 'Xatu Auto Test':
            # you need to change from column to row, and it will work
            row.find_element_by_name("quote_id").click()
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response which as been helpful! Although .click() didn't work for me which is very odd. When I changed that to .send_keys(Keys.SPACE), then it worked.

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot, glad it helps. This is odd, I'm on Firefox driver, are you using Chrome?

Comment: I'm on the Firefox driver as well. It's probably due to the application I'm testing on. Clicking works on other elements on other pages in the same domain though.